# How to block multiple logins using Spring-security?

Tags: spring-security

When the same user log in using different browsers/machines concurrently,user is allowed to login by same credential

With Spring security concurrent session control this can be easily handled by the following configuration in security.xml file:

```xml
<concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
```

Problem: After successful login, user shall be blocked to login again from any other browser/machine, if he close the browser window without clicking logout button. He may be restricted for an session timeout interval.

Answer (score 2):

> After successful login, user shall be blocked to login again from any other browser/machine, if he close the browser window without clicking logout button

Yes. This is what the `<concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1"` does.

If you don't want the user to be locked out you need to set `max-sessions="2"`.

**Or**.

On a successful login you can set a cookie which lives forever and identifies the user browser. So when you get a login request with a different cookie but same username you can invalidate the previous user session and let the new user in.

Comment: I couldn't find security.xml in my Grails application